# Why Heroku don't find moment?

Tags: node.js, heroku

i am creating a discord bot and hosting it on heroku. i installed the moment.js library but it can't find it giving the following error

```
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954612+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'moment'
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954612+00:00 app[worker.1]: Require stack:
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954612+00:00 app[worker.1]: - /app/bot.js
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954622+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954625+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954625+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954626+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954626+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:3:16)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954626+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954626+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954627+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954627+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954627+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954628+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954628+00:00 app[worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/bot.js' ]
2022-03-27T12:41:48.954628+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

my code

```
const moment = require('moment');
```

how should i do?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "freaksland-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/voice": "^0.8.0",
    "moment.js": "^2.29.1",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "init": "^0.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you declare it as a dependency? Please show your `package.json`.

Comment: what should i add?

Comment: i tried to add it, it's okay? because when I tried it in local it went anyway

Comment: There is no `moment.js` on npm. There is only `moment`, so that package.json entry was probably not created from a real npm install command (which is `npm install moment`). However, to make things more pressing: moment.js [is no longer supported](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment). It's getting security updates, and that's all it's getting. Anything you actually want to use it for, other libraries (and plain JS) can do better.

Comment: i wanted to use it to convert date from format
mm / dd / yyyy HH: mm aa
to the format dd / mm / yyyy HH: mm: ss

Comment: Then you want https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat, not moment.js

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, you're right, Moment.js isn't a great library choice in 2022. But the immediate issue here is about installing dependencies on Heroku. Changing libraries won't fix the problem, it will just kick the can down the road and OP will be back trying to install a different library the wrong way.

Comment: i had tried with moment and it worked now i will try to use this and see if it works (in local)

Comment: @Chris that part is covered in the first part of the comment you're replying to: there is no `moment.js` on npm, it's called `moment`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that is only part of the problem. And I agree it was already covered: in the answer I wrote below. The rest of the problem is that OP is trying to manually run `npm install` on Heroku, which will not work.

Comment: Hard to tell, I don't see anything in the post that mentions which buildpack they're using, and I don't see them talk about a procfile that runs `npm install` (I just see a node runtime error) but if you create a node project for heroku, usually it's the node buildpack, which runs `npm install` for you based on your `package.json` - fix the `package.json` dependency and without additional details, I'd fully expect that to fix the problem. @andrex2006 can you please update your post to include whether you have Heroku set to use the Node buildpack or whether you have a custom bootstrap script?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, in a now deleted comment OP showed a different `package.json` before that did not include Moment in _any_ form. They added it to their question but I'm pretty confident they didn't actually push the file shown above to Heroku as it would blow up when it couldn't find the dependency. They also said in a comment (on my answer) that they ran `npm install` manually on Heroku, which will not work.

Comment: i am new to heroku, where can i find it?

Comment: @andrex2006, the answer is my answer below. Please actually try it. This Moment vs. another library stuff is a distraction. Get Moment to install first so you can learn how to actually declare dependencies so Heroku will use them and worry about changing libraries later.

Comment: @andrex2006 it sounds like you added details relevant to your problem somewhere outside your post: even if you provide someone with more information in a comment thread (either on your question, or in response to an answer), please remember to [also update your post](/help/how-to-post) so that everyone has all the details.

Comment: @andrex2006, and please ensure that your post actually contains _accurate_ information. I don't believe you have actually committed the file you show above and deployed from that commit since it would most likely cause a build error. Running `heroku run npm install` is not the same thing as declaring your dependencies.

Comment: now I'm trying to convert it in a different way because there are other libraries in my file and those don't give errors so I try to fix it in the script

Comment: i finally managed to declare the dependency and now it works correctly

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Comment: @andrex2006 this is not how Stackoverflow works, and you know it. Presumably you posted here because you've seen plenty of SO questions and answers and wanted to benefit from the same process, so: follow that process. If someone's answer helped you fix things, upvote (and possibly even accept) their answer. And if you fixed things "on your own" (which isn't on your own given how much conversation happened here) then _post your own answer_ and then you can accept that as being the solution. But at this point, this question is basically a prime candidate for closing.

Answer (score 1):

You are depending on `moment.js`, but [the correct package](https://yarnpkg.com/package/moment) is just `moment`.

Did you manually add that to your `package.json`? First, remove that line.

Then add the correct package:

- If you are using Yarn, run `yarn add moment`
- If you are using NPM, run `npm install moment`

This should install the dependency locally and also add it to your `package.json` and the relevant lock file. Commit the changes to those files and redeploy.

Comment: on heroku I had already done the command npm install moment but it always gave that error even when that line was not there

Comment: @andrex2006, you cannot install things on Heroku by running `npm install`. When you do that you are only modifying a temporary filesystem that will be discarded immediately (if you do it on a one-off dyno) or within about a day (if you manage to run it on a running dyno). You _must_ declare your dependencies and let Heroku install them during its build phase. Please update your `package.json` and lock file, commit those changes, and redeploy as described above.

Comment: (Even if you _could_ install things on Heroku via `npm install` it is a best practice to declare your dependencies.)